# A Kolmogorov inequality for sums of contiguous subsequences

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

If $X_1, \ldots X_n$ are independent real-valued random variables such that $E[X_k] = 0$ and $E[X_k^2]$ is finite for each $k$, Kolmorogov's inequality gives an upper bound on $P[\max_{1\le k \le n}|S_k| < \lambda]$, where $S_k = X_1 + \ldots X_k$. In some work relating to Dvoretzky's stochastic approximation theorem, a colleague and I are looking for a bound where the sums of prefixes $S_k$ are replaced by sums of contiguous subsequences $S_k - S_j$. I.e., under the same assumptions on the $X_k$, we would like a bound, tending to $0$ as $\lambda \to 0$, on $P[\max_{1\le j < k \le n}[|S_k - S_j| < \lambda]$. This seems like a natural thing to ask for, but we haven't been able to find anything in the literature that we can adapt to give such a bound. We would be very grateful for any pointers or hints. Alternatively, we would be very interested in a counter-example showing that $P[\max_{1\le j < k \le n}|S_k - S_j| < \lambda]$ need not tend to $0$ as $\lambda \to 0$.

Edit: apologies, there is a repeated and highly significant typo in the above: "${} < \lambda$" should read "${} > \lambda$" throughout. What we are looking for is an upper bound, tending to $0$ as $\lambda \to \infty$ on $P[\max_{1\le j < k \le n}[|S_k - S_j| > \lambda]$.

Comment: Kolmorogov's maximal inequality provides a **lower** bound on $P(\max_{1\le k \le n}|S_k| < \lambda)$.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use $\Bbb P$ and $\Bbb E$ to denote the probability and the expectation; use $P,E$ or $\mathsf P,\mathsf E$ instead. Blackboard bold is reserved for $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$, $\Bbb Z$, and other similar sets.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: I have changed the notation in the question.

Comment: In fact, I think the amended question actually follows easily from  the Kolmogorov inequality and the triangle inequality. So I think I'lll delete this question as I don't think it adds much value to MO users.

Comment: You should not change the question, especially so drastically, especially after an answer was given (which you gratefully accepted).

Comment: Apologies, there was a repeated and highly significant typo in the above: "${} < \lambda$" should read "${} > \lambda$" throughout. What we were looking for is an upper bound, tending to $0$ as $\lambda \to \infty$ on $P[\max_{1\le j < k \le n}[|S_k - S_j| > \lambda]$. That turns out to be easier to find that we thought at first (using the Kolmogorov and triangle inequalities), so I am happy with the answer given below, as it resolves the original (unintended) question.

Comment: You also had $\lambda$ going to $0$, rather than $\infty$. So, whatever the value of the original or changed question may be, the post should not be deleted.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: sure! thanks for all your time on what turned out to be a diversion which turned out not to be relevant to my current problem but may perhaps help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p_i:=P(X_i=0)>0$ for all $i$, then
$$P_n(\lambda):=P(\max_{1\le j < k \le n}|S_k - S_j| < \lambda)\ge P(X_1=0,\dots,X_n=0)=p_1\cdots p_n>0$$
for all $\lambda>0$, so that $P_n(\lambda)\not\to0$ as $\lambda \downarrow 0$.

Comment: Many thanks! That will save us a lot of time exploring a dead-end.

Comment: I am glad this was of help.

Comment: Sorry, I made a significant error in the statement of the question. See the edit.